# WPF DropShadowEffect for Canvas and ClipToBounds

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am having a Canvas inside a scrollviewer. Canvas supports zoom functionality also. I want to have DropShadowEffect for Canvas. DropShadowEffect is working only when ClipToBounds of Canvas is set to False. But I want to set it to True. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: A little code goes a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is to layer different controls in a grid and attach the DropShadowEffect to the control in the background.

Something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <Grid>
    <Canvas ClipToBounds="true" Background="Transparent" />
    <Border Margin="2,2,5,5" Background="LightBlue" >
      <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2"></DropShadowEffect>
      </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Not perfect. The border will be shifted in position slightly behind the canvas because of the shadow itself.